# can't display error messages with customErrors=Off in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I changed the following web.config:

```
1- VirtualDirectory\80\web.config
2- 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config
3- 14\TEMPLATE\ADMIN\web.config
4- 14\CONFIG\web.config

CallStack="True", Debug="True" and customErrors="Off"
```

on all the 4 web.config files but still I can't display the detailed error message

I only get this: 
server error in "/" application runtime error

and some instruction on how to display the detailed error message.

I need your help.

Comment: Have you tried an `iisreset`?

Comment: Yes but nothing changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this link [Sharepoint 2010 Server Error '/' in Application](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/wss-search/sharepoint-2010-server-error-in-application-42707) , you have to change the `web.config` of central administration too , then `iisreset` , please let me know if it works .

Comment: Three Locations: 1) `inetpub\wwwroot\wss\Virtual directories folder\[Central Admin PortNo]\web.config`. 2) 
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\ADMIN\web.config`. 3) 
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\Layouts\web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

This post help me out on SharePoint 2013. It explains step by step how to enable custom errors [Enable Debugging and set custom errors off in SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/voyage/archive/2014/09/02/enable-debugging-and-set-custom-errors-off-in-sharepoint.aspx).

Three key areas that the post mention are:

1. Turn on the call stack (CallStack="true")
2. Disable custom errors ()
3. Enable debugging ()

on the locations given on the article.